# US B2 visa was denied

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, german-residents, croatian-citizens

I am a 20 year old student. I was born and have lived in Croatia for 16 years, then I moved to Germany with my mother and started studying here. I have a legitimate record of attending school and working here, although not working full time and mostly for stretches of around 3 to 6 months at a time because of school.

I have been denied because I do not have strong enough connections to Germany. I don't know how I can prove that I plan to return, when I can't have a stable job as a 20 year old without a degree. I'm still mostly dependent on my mother as well, though I have sufficient funds to last me in America.

My biggest problem is that I already have booked my ticket- and a return ticket and it's in less than 3 months. Would getting a part time job increase my chances? Should I just reapply as I have previously and not stupidly mention having friends in the US?

I also plan to apply in another city (the reason being that travelling there is more convenient and cheaper), and can the person interviewing me see what the previous person asked me and what I answered? 
If so, have I messed up really bad by already saying I know someone in the US? 
Was the reason for them rejecting me because I preferred answering the questions in English instead of German?

Additionally, I have doctor's appointments and concerts already planned for ***AFTER*** my return from the US. Would presenting those be of any help in my situation?

Comment: You don't need to have tickets to get a US visa, so it was a bad move to buy them before getting a visa. Whatever you decide to do, don't lie in visa applications. If you're found to be lying, you're quite likely to be banned from entry.

Comment: Just forget it. Visit somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

If this is for a trip in 3 months and you’ve already been denied, I would do my best to try to get either a refund, reschedule your trip for a year in the future, or change to another destination country. In other words, you’re not coming to the USA this year.

There’s no appeal process for the current application (except for situations where there was a serious error, such as looking at the wrong person’s file). From what you’ve told us, your denial is within the realm of understandable decisions given your current circumstances and so applying again now  will just result in another denial. In any case, you’ll have to say that you’ve already been denied when you apply. Your current denial and the rationale will be in your records and lying about it will get you a lifetime  ban.

Instead, you need to materially change your circumstances for when you apply in a year or so: graduate, get a full time job, an apartment that you’re paying for yourself or your own house, a family, a travel record of going to other non-EU countries, etc.

This isn’t something that can happen in three months thus my advice that you give up hope of going to the USA this year.

Comment: US deception bans do not expire.

Comment: @phoog thx, fixed.